# copy files to server from relative path in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

How can I pass a relative path so that Ansible can copy files from `node/keys` and copy them to a server?

The playbook is `ansible/playbook`.

My directory structure is:

```
├── ansible
│   ├── inventory
│   └── playbook
├── node
│   ├── keys
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── utils
└── shell
    ├── data.json
    ├── create-data.sh
    ├── destory.sh
    └── firewall-rules.sh
```

Below is the playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    source: "{{ source }}"
    destination: /home/ubuntu

  tasks: 

    - name: Copy files
      copy: 
        src:  "{{ source }}"
        dest: "{{ destination }}"
```

That's how I run:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yaml playbook/crypto-generate.yaml
 --extra-vars "source=../node/keys"
```

I am trying to pass a relative path.

Comment: Do you recieve an error or are the files just not copied?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach. Just made a quick test and it works for me. What is the exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: It can't find the file. It looks here /ansible/playbook/files/../node/keys. I am not sure it looks for ansible/files

Comment: can anyone help me wtih the issue ?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You can use absolute paths with src that avoids the problems of not knowing where is the root folder.

> Local path to a file to copy to the remote server. This can be
>   absolute or relative. If path is a directory, it is copied
>   recursively. In this case, if path ends with "/", only inside contents
>   of that directory are copied to destination. Otherwise, if it does not
>   end with "/", the directory itself with all contents is copied. This
>   behavior is similar to the rsync command line tool.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html

Comment: I don't want to have strict absolute path because i can put this script in any machine

Comment: You do not have to. You can construct the absolute path very easily everywhere.

Comment: But in that case i need to change ansible script everytime if i move my code. In assible how can i get i do that ?

Comment: you can combine pwd + relative path without changing the code

Comment: As Istvan says, like `ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yaml playbook/crypto-generate.yaml --extra-vars "source=$(pwd)/../node/keys"`.

Answer (score 33):

I am using `{{ playbook_dir }}` to construct full path,see
[special ansible variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)

```
- name: Copy files
  copy: 
    src:  "{{ playbook_dir }}/../../node/keys"
    dest: "{{ destination }}"
```